# Error creating a line chart on top on a bar chart from a data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to create a line chart right on top of a stacked bar chart that shares the same x-axis. So far, I've come up with this code but I'm stuck for hours trying to complete the remaining code for the line chart as I've encountered a KeyError when trying to reference the column names for the line chart after transposing the data frame.

```
#Slices the dataset to create stacked bar chart
df1 = df.iloc[1:6]

plt.figure(1, figsize=(10,10))
barchart = df1.T.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
plt.twinx()
linechart = plt.plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the first column of `df.T` and then create a pandas line plot similar to the bar plot. The code below first creates a toy dataframe similar to the data in the question to draw a bar plot and an aligned line plot. The legends of both plots can be combined via `get_legend_handles_labels()`. Note that pandas plot functions don't return a plot, but the matplotlib `ax` on which the plot was created.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 5
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.randint(5000, 7000, N), np.random.randint(1200, 1400, N), np.random.randint(500, 700, N),
                   np.random.randint(900, 1500, N), np.random.randint(1100, 1400, N), np.random.randint(1700, 2300, N)],
                  columns=['2019 Q1', '2019 Q2', '2019 Q3', '2019 Q4', '2020 Q1'],
                  index=['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee', 'fff'])
df['2020 Q1'] *= 0.6
df1 = df.iloc[1:]

ax1 = df1.T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df.T['aaa'].plot(kind='line', color='navy', marker='*', ls='-', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin=0)

h1, l1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
h2, l2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
ax1.legend(h2 + h1, l2 + l1)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: I really appreciate the reply, though I'm now getting a TypeError: no numeric data to plot when trying to run the code

Comment: Maybe you have some strings in your data?

Comment: Apparently transposing the data frame causes extra whitespaces on the columns for my data frame which was causing the issues for me. But your code solved my problem perfectly. Thank you!